# Shouldn't set and order of binding sources depend on HTTP verb?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am a bit confused. I have action method (asp.net core 2.1) with this signature:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<DeviceTypeDTO> Get(GetDeviceTypeRequest request)
```

When I make a request I get a 400 error with the message:

> A non-empty request body is required.

First, I'd like to understand why it stops and does not try to bind the model from query string. At least I would expect this behaviour after reading the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1#how-model-binding-works).

By the way, as soon as I apply `[FromQuery]` attribute everything works fine.

Second, why is it trying to get data from body in the first place for `Get` method?

**update**

It [looks like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1#binding-source-parameter-inference) after binding source is inferred no other sources are probed. The reason for this is applied `[ApiController]` attribute. Without it model binder tries to get data from multiple sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, I'd like to understand why it stops and does not try to bind the model from query string.

The `[ApiController]` attribute  adds customisations to the [Application Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/application-model?view=aspnetcore-2.1) used in ASP.NET Core MVC. One of those customisations is in how the source for model-binding is determined. For each action that is found, the [`InferParameterBindingSources`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/2.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/ApiBehaviorApplicationModelProvider.cs#L143) function inside of [`ApiBehaviorApplicationModelProvider`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/2.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/ApiBehaviorApplicationModelProvider.cs) is called, which includes the following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < actionModel.Parameters.Count; i++)
{
    var parameter = actionModel.Parameters[i];
    var bindingSource = parameter.BindingInfo?.BindingSource;
    if (bindingSource == null)
    {
        bindingSource = InferBindingSourceForParameter(parameter);

        parameter.BindingInfo = parameter.BindingInfo ?? new BindingInfo();
        parameter.BindingInfo.BindingSource = bindingSource;
    }
}
```

The call to [`InferBindingSourceForParameter`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/2.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/ApiBehaviorApplicationModelProvider.cs#L221) is most relevant here, which includes the following code:

```
var bindingSource = IsComplexTypeParameter(parameter) ?
    BindingSource.Body :
    BindingSource.Query;
```

As can be seen above, the code checks the parameter (`GetDeviceTypeRequest request` in your example) to see if it it's complex (which it is in your example). Given that it is in fact complex, the parameter is configured to be consumed from the body of the request.

> Second, why is it trying to get data from body in the first place for Get method?

As this all runs as part of configuring the ASP.NET Core MVC application model, there is no in-flight context to determine whether or not this is a GET or a POST request. Having said that, I imagine it would be easy enough to use the `[HttpGet]` attribute that's on the action itself to determine that the request will be a GET request, but I can't be sure it's quite that simple. This could be raised as an issue on GitHub for ASP.NET Core MVC, but it would be a *breaking change*.

Comment: So the main point is that after binding source is inferred no other attempts are made in case of binding failure, and it returns immediately with 400.

Comment: Ok then, at least I'd add this to docs. Model binding behaviour differs a lot with and without `[ApiController]`.

Comment: Yes, I agree. There is documentation on the topic itself [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#binding-source-parameter-inference), but linking to that from the page you've been using would be helpful. You can raise it as an issue on the docs page itself if you like (I don't mind doing it if you'd rather not).